# Issue making JWT token for use with Rails and rest-client gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jwt, rest-client

I'm new to Rails and I'm using rest-client to make outbound requests. It's easy to get successful results for a simple call like this:

```
@obj  = RestClient.get 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1'
```

I need to hit a real endpoint and send a header with a jwt token (using ruby-jwt). According to the [JWT readme](https://jwt.io/introduction/), the content of the header should look like this:

```
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

So I have some code to use a secret to make that token (and I confirmed the resulting token is valid) and put it into a headers variable, but **I'm unsure about the syntax on that headers line, and whether it's right to use strings**:

```
def build_headers (secret)
  jwt_token = make_signed_JWT_token(secret)
  headers = ("Authorization: Bearer "+ jwt_token) 
  return headers
end
```

Running it produces a 'headers' value like this:

```
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1MzIxMTc3MjF9.dP2k1oPwjna5HdrnFeSqiVfR0Fz6J1ZlupfXMsPtFKw
```

I include that in my rest-client invocation like so:

```
@obj = RestClient.get(path, headers)
```

I'm no longer get a 401 Unauthorized error, but no celebrating yet; **we appear to jump out of the code block at that line, with this exception**:

```
undefined method `delete_if' for #<String:0x007f9e4de410b8>
```

Looking in the rest-client code, there is exactly one block that uses delete_if, whose purpose is to find and extract/remove "params" key if the value is a Hash/ParamsArray:

```
  headers.delete_if do |key, value|
    if key.to_s.downcase == 'params' &&
        (value.is_a?(Hash) || value.is_a?(RestClient::ParamsArray))
      if url_params
        raise ArgumentError.new("Multiple 'params' options passed")
      end
      url_params = value
      true
    else
      false
    end
```

So my error suggests that it found something in this forbidden format and is trying to delete it, but that delete method isn't defined to act on a String. My best hunch is that there's something the matter with that headers item I created, but reading around I'm not finding more clues. Has anyone seen this before, or know if my jwt/header should be different?

Comment: the docs for `RestClient` state that you should use Hash like this `RestClient.get 'http://example.com/resource', {:Authorization => 'Bearer cT0febFoD5lxAlNAXHo6g'}`, see https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client#headers foor more details.

Comment: thank you, @fanta! This is a big help- I had seen that but I'm still a bit unclear. To confirm, in this case we have a hash table called "Authorization" and the name/value pair is "Bearer" and the token, is that right? When I try for ":Authorization", RubyMine won't let me use a capital A or colon beforehand- is there a trick to that? I can only do it like so: authorization["Bearer"] = jwt_token

Comment: are you trying to create a hash with name `Authorization` ?. The `Hash` should be your headers, the key is `Authorization` and the value is `Bearer xxxxxxxxxx`, like: `headers = { Authorization: "Bearer #{jwt_token}" }`, and then use it like `@obj = RestClient.get(path, headers)`

Comment: Thank you- that works! I needed that syntax with the curly braces for the variable name, and now this makes sense that the Bearer and token can be the value together. Thanks so much for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a string where a hash is expected. Try this:

```
def build_headers (secret)
  jwt_token = make_signed_JWT_token(secret)
  headers = { authorization: "Bearer "+ jwt_token }
  return headers
end
```

Comment: yes thank you! This is the same advice that @fanta gave above- thank you for the help!